# How to set the deployment target when running clang with "syntax-only" option

Tags: objective-c, xcode, emacs, clang, llvm-clang

How can I properly propagate the *deployment target* setting to `clang`
when using the `-fsyntax-only` option?

I'm running the `clang` process from the Emacs `flycheck-mode` in order to check the syntax
of the Objective-C code. Here is the slightly edited command line invocation:

```
Tue Apr 15 11:49:16 2014
clang failed with error 1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -fsyntax-only -x objective-c -std=gnu99 -fblocks -fobjc-arc -fno-builtin -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -D__OBJC__ -DTARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR -DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet)) -DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName))) -DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction) -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=70000 -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -FExampleApp -include ExampleApp/ExampleApp/ExampleApp-Prefix.pch -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include  -code-completion-at -:473:3 -

In file included from <built-in>:165:
In file included from <command line>:7:
In file included from /Users/rk/Developer/ExampleApp/src/ios/./ExampleApp/ExampleApp/ExampleApp-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:106:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSProgress.h:14:5: error: the current deployment target does not support automated __weak references
    __weak id _group;
    ^
```

The problem is that obviously the *deplyoment target* is not set
correctly.  I've tried setting the enviroment variable:

```
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
```

to no avail.  Unfortunately, when using the `-fsyntax-only` option `clang` doesn't
accept `-mios-simulator-version-min=7.0` option.

Answer (score 1):

clang supports the following flags for setting the deployment target:

```
-mios-version-min=<value>
-mmacosx-version-min=<value>
```

So in your case, you probably want to find a way to pass `-mios-version-min=7.0` to clang.